# Sum one column in list based on second column

Tags: c#

I would like to sum one column in list collection based on another column.

This is how class looks like

```
Date           Payment

2015-09-09     500
2015-09-09     200
2017-01-03     150
2017-01-03     300
```

Result should be like this

```
Date           Payment

2015-09-09     700
2017-01-03     450
```

Code:

```
var result = from e in scheduleDetails
         let k = new
         {
             Date = e.ActualDueDate
         }
         group e by k into t
         select new
         {
             Date = t.Key.Date,
             Payment = t.Sum(e => e.EscrowPayment)
         };

List<ScheduleDetails> temp = result.Select(t => new ScheduleDetails(t.Date, t.Payment)).ToList();
```

I do not want the anonymous type to be created hence I map it to the original object. For this, **I had to create the constructor**.

```
public ScheduleDetails(DateTime? date, decimal? payment)
{
    this.ActualDueDate = date;
    this.EscrowPayment = payment;
}
```

**Questions:**

- Is this the best way to achieve this?
- I want resultant object to be same as input object only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create new range variable and anonymous type:

```
var temp = scheduleDetails.GroupBy(sd => sd.ActualDueDate)
                 .Select(g => new ScheduleDetails(g.Key, g.Sum(sd => sd.EscrowPayment)))
                 .ToList();
```

Also if `ScheduleDetails` class has public setters for it's `ActualDueDate` and `EscrowPayment` properties, you can use object initializer without adding  constructor:

```
.Select(g => new ScheduleDetails { 
   ActualDueDate = g.Key, 
   EscrowPayment = g.Sum(sd => sd.EscrowPayment)
})
```

Query syntax (note that temp will be `IEnumerable<ScheduleDetails>` here):

```
var temp = from sd in scheduleDetails
           group sd by sd.ActualDueDate into g
           select new ScheduleDetails { 
              ActualDueDate = g.Key, 
              EscrowPayment = g.Sum(sd => sd.EscrowPayment)
           };
```

Comment: Input had 40 rows, now it has 10 but the `ActualDueDate`  and `EscrowPayment` are null for every record.

Comment: @Shaggy it's impossible. ActualDueDate is used for grouping. If you have 10 groups, then you should have 10 different values for ActualDueDate in result

Comment: [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb549393(v=vs.110).aspx) has got an extension that allows you to `Select` directly. This can be shortened as `.GroupBy(sd => sd.ActualDueDate, (k, g) => new ScheduleDetails(k, g.Sum(sd => sd.EscrowPayment)))`.

Comment: @Shaggy check if you have property assignments in the constructor: `this.ActualDueDate = date` and `this.EscrowPayment = payment`

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy : Is it possible without the constructor ?